# onBackPressed() not working

Tags: android, button, back

I'm trying to close my app on a back button click. From the main screen, the back button takes you to a credits screen.  From that credits screen, I want to close the app with the back button.  Unfortunately, the onBackPressed() method I'm calling doesn't seem to be executed at all.  I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
package app.jonward.boss;
import android.app.Activity;


public class Credits extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.credits);

    //Doing stuff
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   finish();
   return;
}

}
```

Comment: Have you implemented onKeyDown() or onKeyUp() by any chance?  Are they failing to call super.onKeyDown/onKeyUp()?  Are they returning true?  Are there widgets in your application that implemented onKeyDown()/onKeyUp() and are returning true for the back key?  Any of these things could keep the back key from reaching your onBackPressed() method.

Comment: the ONLY thing happening in this code is drawing some textviews. that's it. but onBackPressed() isn't being executed when the Back button is being pressed.

Comment: One final thought: onBackPressed() is new in 2.0.  On a 1.x system, it would never get called.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I'm having a similar problem with one (and only one) of my Activities.

Answer (score 3):

I don't get it. What `onBackPressed()` does *is* to call `finish()`. `finish()` is an `Activity` method, there's no way to "quit" your app, so to speak. Perhaps what you really want is to call `finish()` on the Activity that is starting the `Credits` activity. Inside the other activity:

```
   finish();
   startActivity(this, Credits.class);
```

Comment: I dont think you understand what I'm trying to do. I want to use the back button on the phone to leave the credits screen (in essence, exiting the application). Yes, I know Android apps don't really terminate. The issue at this point is that onBackPressed() isn't being executed when the back button is pressed.

Comment: nothing changes. the activity shows as it's supposed to. it's accessed by pressing back from the title screen. i wanted to exit the app by pressing back again, but it doesn't do that by default.

Comment: Then I have no clue, something seems screwed up with your activity stack, but I can't see anything that is wrong with the snippet you shared, sorry.

Comment: I agree with the above. The back button as default behaviour will close the activity but from what I understand you want to override this functionality. The two code statements you have used and my answer have worked both fine in my example. Something is wrong, as stated above, with your activity stack (or I hate to state the obvious, the wrong key is being pressed).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following solution?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: I've tried that as well and nothing happens. I have no errors, no warnings, nothing that would tell me I've left an include or anything out.  Just, nothing happens. Do I need to add an onClickListener somewhere?

Comment: It shouldn't need one. Have you tried replacing `finish()` with a simple log message or Toast message to see if it's called at all, just in case there is an issue with `finish()`?

Comment: Yes, I put a toast message in there and it didn't work, either. The code isn't being executed and I can't figure out why :/

Comment: FWIW, this code snippet doesn't really do anything since that's what super.onKeyDown() would have done anyway -- call finish().  (Someone correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: alright, then... what exactly am i supposed to do when i want the back button to close the program? i dont care if the process terminates; i know that's not how android really handles processes. i just want my program to go away and the home screen to come back.

Answer (score 1):

Just recently, i ran into this issue and i was able to solve it by deleting all the folders in the `build` directory.

[image: Snapshot of which directory to delete]

I don't know how but it seemed that `Android Studio` made an error generating the build and that lead to this problem. So after deleting the `build` directory, my`onBackpressed()` method was being called.

Comment: Weird but this worked for me. Thanks for your discovery. +1

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i am not able to comment yet (I wanted this to be a comment on Muffinbubble's answer)..

Try putting the onKeyDown into your mainclass and validate if this get's called even if you are in your second Activity.
You could then check where you are via the main class and exit the application if needed and else return super.onKeyDown(..).

Comment: Excellent point:  if in doubt, scatter some printfs in your code (Log.d(...) in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have found an answer yet, but have you tried super.onBackPressed from within your overriding method?

If I were you, I would try:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```