# overriding the onBackPressed() not responding

Tags: android

I was working on an app similar to the ' Diaro ' app and the ' MyDiary ' app on android.

The main activity in my app is the DiaryActivity which controls all other activities.  When the add button is pressed, a new activity is opened, the user enters data in an edit text field, on pressing the back button the item gets saved in the database and gets displayed in a list, (the list is a part of the main activity).

NOW THE PROBLEM with the main activity is that, on pressing the back button, the application instead of shutting down, takes the control back to the main activity, only this time, the last entry made is not present, also it is only now if the back button is present again, the application shuts down.

I thought the possible solution could be overriding the onBackPressed() function and writing finish() function in that, but that didn't work.

The code for the activity is here.

http://pastebin.com/ugMdVsbW

Comment: you can call finish() when you click on the 'add' button in MainActity.

Comment: Vivek you are a genius:D hats off to you man,thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
}
```

no need to write `finish()`,

`super.onBackPressed()` will do the job.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: It's not even needed to overwrite `onBackPressed()` at all if this is the implementation OP wants. That's the system default behavior.

Comment: I thought that, but the problem is , even if I remove the function, still the main activity is not shutting down.

Comment: hi @hotveryspicy if we use finish means it will close the live activity. else if we wont use finish means back button pressing wont do any work.

Comment: I tried other stackoverflow questions , which matched my problem like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565484/onbackpressed-not-working , but no help

Comment: hi @  android noob after every startActivity(); use finish() line.  it will close the activity before moving to another page. hope this will help you

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558385/android-onbackpressed-not-working

Comment: yes I forgot to add finish() function and that is why the errors were reported, thanks guys it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I am using following code. Try with this code

```
@Override 
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){ 

        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) { //stop your music here
             // To exit application
                 finish();
        } 
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code and work fine,

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
   if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
   {       
      back();
   }

   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public void back()
{
   startActivity(new Intent(this, Home.class));
}
```

Comment: maybe you dont need "return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);". I'm a young developer, i'm just try to help«